# have to to display specific content for each group of user django

Tags: python, sql, django, database

i want to display specific content for each group of user.
for example i have a course table and an course object belong to one or more MasterGroup and
each user can belong to one or more MasterGroup .

```
class MasterGroup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SolveGroup(models.Model):
    master_group_id = models.ManyToManyField(MasterGroup ,related_name='fk_solve_master')
    age_from = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    age_to = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    have_job=  models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False,blank=False)
```

do they suggest a specific solution to this problem?

Comment: You haven't shown any form of expected output. Please, have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view:

```
user = request.user
objects = yourmodel.objects.filter(group_field__in=user.groups_table.all())
```